# How Fetch AppDynamics Reports in Java

Tags: appdynamics

Do we have any opensource or any proven code which collects  the App Dynamics reports from App Dynamics Servers ?

Comment: Can you be more specific, which "reports" are you referring to?

Comment: I am talking about the information what we defined in the AppD Widgets !!

Comment: So you want to send a scheduled report for an existing dashboard?

Comment: So , I mean , when we run some Load test or when we have some Production transactions happened , I want to fetch a separate report ( May be a  Excel or Pie Char or anything else )  from AppD Dashboard and Send those to my respective leads ...

Answer (score 0):

Generally the workflow for sending reports from AppDynamics is as follows:

1. Create a Custom Dashboard - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Custom+Dashboards
2. Add Widgets to your Dashboard containing the tables, charts etc that you want to see in your report - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Widgets
3. Now you can send a report (one-off or scheduled) by configuring a report based off the Dashboard you have created, including setting the time range of the report - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Reports

Note: There is a sample custom dashboard .json available here to get you started: https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Sample-Custom-Dashboard-for-Business-Transaction-Report/ta-p/21264

Note: There are already many "Standard Reports" which could make things easier depending on use case.

Note: If you instead want to export data and then analyse with your own tooling, then see the docs on Public API's available here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/AppDynamics+APIs